# How to connect and obtain a blood pressure monitor from the Beurer brand with Flutter application (device BM 96)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, monitoring, device, health-monitoring

How can I connect a Beurer BM96 blood pressure monitor device that works with Bluetooth to Flutter? I want to connect my Flutter application with this device, and when the patient measures their blood pressure, I want the measurements to be recorded in Firebase and at the same time displayed on the screen of my application. How can I do this, please? Should I use the flutter_blue_plus package, and then how can I read the measurements from the device? Do I need to know any other information about this device? If so, how can I obtain this information?

i will try package flutter_blue_plus and i don't know what's the next step, should i know other informations about this device ? How can I obtain this information?I didn't find anything on the internet like what i want to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Beurer appears to provide documentation for their products if you register as a developer. I would start there. https://connect.beurer.com/developer/en-us/#/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned packages are definitely suitable to connect to a BLE device and read values from them. You now need to obtain information about the service you want to connect to. With a bit of luck it is the official [Blood Pressure Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bls-1-1-1/) with the UUID 0x1810 (see the [Assigned Numbers Document](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/)).

But it is not a requirement for manufacturers to always use a predefined and well documented BLE service, they are free to implement their own custom communication. If that is the case you would need to get information about them from the manufacturer of your BLE device or try to reverse engineer them.

You can start by scanning the device for available services using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to see if you are able to find a predefined service and read values from it.